# ServiceStack - extending AutoQuery Metadata Viewer

Tags: servicestack, servicestack-autoquery

ServiceStack's [AutoQuery Viewer Plugin](https://github.com/ServiceStack/Admin) allows you to decorate the AutoQueries using AutoQuery metadata attributes. I use the existing Metadata service in AutoQuery to power a front-end and display search queries (similar to the existing AutoQuery Admin Feature)

How can I extend/ add additional properties to the AutoQueryViewerAttribute, such that they are available in the Autoquery metadata service?

Current list of AutoQuery attributes available:

```
public class AutoQueryViewerAttribute : AttributeBase
{
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public string IconUrl { get; set; }

    public string BrandUrl { get; set; }

    public string BrandImageUrl { get; set; }

    public string TextColor { get; set; }

    public string LinkColor { get; set; }

    public string BackgroundColor { get; set; }

    public string BackgroundImageUrl { get; set; }

    public string DefaultSearchField { get; set; }

    public string DefaultSearchType { get; set; }

    public string DefaultSearchText { get; set; }

    public string DefaultFields { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to extend the list of AutoQueryViewerAttribute attributes and add two additional properties:

```
public string SourceDescription { get; set; }

public string SourceApplicationName { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't extend the `[AutoQueryViewer]` attribute which is hard coded. The Info on the Attribute is used to populate the [Typed AutoQueryMetadataResponse DTO](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/b49fce4b7211031eb8be72aff87a1f1c3b622b9b/src/ServiceStack/AutoQueryMetadataFeature.cs#L173) which is what's serialized to provide the AutoQuery metadata services. I've just added Meta String Dictionaries on the `MetadataType`, `AutoQueryViewerConfig`, `AutoQueryViewerUserInfo`, `AutoQueryOperation` and `AutoQueryMetadataResponse` DTO in [this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/b49fce4b7211031eb8be72aff87a1f1c3b622b9b) so you can attach additional metadata to the AutoQuery metadata DTOs using the `MetadataFilter`, e.g:

```
Plugins.Add(new AutoQueryMetadataFeature {
    MetadataFilter = response => {
        response.Meta = new Dictionary<string,string> {
           { "SourceApplicationName", "My App" },
           { "SourceDescription", "My App Description" },
        };
    }
});
```

This change is available from **v4.5.13** that's now [available on MyGet](http://docs.servicestack.net/myget).

Comment: Wow - the servicestack support is world class ! Thanks for an awesome product and continuous improvement